# Simple Map/Reduce MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongovue

I am trying to get a simple map reduce working in MongoVUE, but it doesn't return any results, I just want to get it to output the count of each userID just so I can have a working example to build from.

```
function Map() {
emit( this.UpdatedBy.UserId, {"count": 1} );
}

function Reduce(key, values) {

var result = {count: 0};
  values.forEach(function(value) {
  result.count += value.count;
});
return result;
}

function Finalize(key, reduced) {
/*  
reduced = Transform-to-Desired-Form(reduced);
*/
return reduced;
}
```

And the output is set to inline.

This is the tutorial I am working from, but I just want to apply a simple count to start off with http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial/

Comment: did you check this on mongodb shell?

Comment: I'd like to know why MongoVUE doesn't report any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function() {
    emit( this.UpdatedBy.UserId, 1 );
  };


  function(key, values) {
    var result =  0;

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result += value;
    });
    return result;
  };
```

Here is how I got it to work for anyone who needs a simple example on how to group and count a user Id.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a [blog pos](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/mongodb-mapreduce-vs-sql-server-group-by-which-is-faster/)t and made two short screencasts showing exactly how to get an example MapReduce working in MongoVue